# Recommend a JS game engine for a Tower Defense game

Tags: javascript

I have recently started developing games in javascript, and i have started to look for a game engine. Thought I am planning to develop a Tower Defense game, I would like a game engine which i can use for other games in the future as well. :)

But its very much a jungle out there, and I don't really have the time to dive into all those frameworks, so I was hoping someone could recommend one for me.

I have been looking at ImpactJS, aswell as Cocos2D, so a comment on either would be very much appreciated.

Might be worth mentioning that I am targeting both mobile platforms & desktops. :)

Thank you.